# Is there a way to use 1 git repo to populate several home directories?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to use 1 git repo to populate several home directories?

EX. I have my repo named server-master, and I want git to populate:
/home/user1/
/home/user2/
etc.

The problem I'm running into is I can't clone server-master to /home because the directory already exists, and is not empty.

I can probably create a branch for each user, but that doesn't seem like an appropriate way.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do the users already have home directories or do you need to create the users as well? Do you mean that `/home/user1/.git` etc. should exist, or do you want one combined repository for all of `/home`? Should all the home directories start out the same, or do `user1` and `user2` have different files (and if it’s the second, why don’t you think branches are the right tool for the job?).

Comment: In short: This is a very uncommon thing to want to do, so we need more context than we otherwise might to figure out what you’re doing and answer your question.

Comment: one combined repository for MOST of /home, but not all of it.  I'm managing files for all the users.

Comment: Please put more details in the question. By “MOST of /home”, do you mean that you aren’t managing some users, or that each user will have files not in the repo? How does this work with the typical permissions model, given that only `root` can read all the files and Git creates files owned by the calling process?

Answer (score 0):

The context is not clear enough. Here're some hints that may help.

1.You can specify a name for the local repository that's created by `git clone`, so that the default name won't be used.

```
git clone <url> -- <name>
```

2.You can checkout revisions into different working trees by [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). It's a feature since v2.10.0.